# Exited with exit code 3 on running heroku local

Tags: python, django, heroku, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to use the heroku command line tool following the tutorial on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local
It exited with exit code 3.

```
$ heroku local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
01:53:43 web.1   |  [2017-12-30 01:53:43 +0000] [13114] [INFO] Starting      gunicorn 19.4.5
01:53:43 web.1   |  [2017-12-30 01:53:43 +0000] [13114] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (13114)
01:53:43 web.1   |  [2017-12-30 01:53:43 +0000] [13114] [INFO] Using worker: sync
01:53:43 web.1   |  [2017-12-30 01:53:43 +0000] [13119] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13119
01:53:43 web.1   |  [2017-12-30 01:53:43 +0000] [13119] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
01:53:43 web.1   |  Traceback (most recent call last):
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
01:53:43 web.1   |      worker.init_process()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
01:53:43 web.1   |      self.load_wsgi()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
01:53:43 web.1   |      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
01:53:43 web.1   |      self.callable = self.load()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
01:53:43 web.1   |      return self.load_wsgiapp()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
01:53:43 web.1   |      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 366, in import_app
01:53:43 web.1   |      __import__(module)
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/home/palak/python-getting-started/gettingstarted/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
01:53:43 web.1   |      from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
01:53:43 web.1   |  ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
01:53:43 web.1   |  Traceback (most recent call last):
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
01:53:43 web.1   |      worker.init_process()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
01:53:43 web.1   |      self.load_wsgi()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
01:53:43 web.1   |      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
01:53:43 web.1   |      self.callable = self.load()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
01:53:43 web.1   |      return self.load_wsgiapp()
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
01:53:43 web.1   |      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 366, in import_app
01:53:43 web.1   |      __import__(module)
01:53:43 web.1   |    File "/home/palak/python-getting-started/gettingstarted/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
01:53:43 web.1   |      from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
01:53:43 web.1   |  ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
01:53:43 web.1   |  [2017-12-30 01:53:43 +0000] [13119] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13119)
01:53:43 web.1   |  [2017-12-30 01:53:43 +0000] [13114] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
01:53:43 web.1   |  [2017-12-30 01:53:43 +0000] [13114] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
01:53:43 web.1   Exited with exit code 3
```

It is looking in python2.7 by default while django is installed and is working in python3.6

How do I change this path to python3.6 from python2.7?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual environment needs to be enabled before running 'heroku local'
To activate virtualenv:

```
pipenv shell
```